macOS keyboard shortcut for selected item in the list SwiftUI
Situation and problem:

I'm building to do list macOS app for practice

In my view, I have a list, which loops through an [Task] array (from swiftData query)

The list is selectable

I want to apply a keyboard shortcut to the toggle task.isCompleted for the selected item

I understand you can use the .keyboardShortcut modifier.


Button("complete") {
  // do something
}
.keyboardShortcut("c", modifiers: [.command])

However, I don't know how to apply this shortcut to the selected item only.
List

Item A
Item B <-- selected (expect: cmd+c will perform action for this item)
Item C

The minimum reproducible code:
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query private var tasks: [TaskModel]
    @State private var selections: Set<TaskModel> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selections) {
            ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
                HStack {
                    
                    Button("complete") {
                        task.isCompleted.toggle()
                    }
                    
                    Text(task.name)
                }
                // How to perform keyboard shortcut on the selected row?
            }
        }
    }
}


@Model
class TaskModel {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String, isCompleted: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
}


I would use onKeyPress to detect a key event. Just add the following to the List
.onKeyPress(phases: .down) { press in
    guard press.key == "c", 
          press.modifiers == .command,
          !selections.isEmpty else {
        // return .ignored to produce the sound effect indicating an invalid action
        return .ignored
    }
    for selection in selections {
        selection.isCompleted.toggle()
    }
    return .handled
}

Use .onKeyPress(phases: [.down, .repeat]) if you want it to be toggled repeatedly when the keys are held down.
Side notes:

ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) doesn't make much sense when TaskModel already has an id and is Identifiable. Just write ForEach(tasks).
Declaring your own id property in a @Model gives up the default implementation of Identifiable provided by PersistentModel. This could be problem if id is not unique.
I would avoid using command + C as the keyboard shortcut for toggling completion, as it is commonly associated with "copy".


Thank you. It works for the first time. But after pressing the keyboard shortcut, I can't do anything else. In my case I have a textfield and pressing enter won't focus on that textfield. But if I restart the simulator and press enter, it will focus on the textfield. Any thought on why this happens?

@dev_dev Why do you expect the text field to be focused when you press enter? Text fields don't generally do that. Where is the text field?

The TextField is inside the HStack; change the Text to TextField in my example.

@dev_dev I cannot reproduce that on macOS 14.5. After I press command+c, pressing enter still focuses on the TextField on the selected row.

@dev_dev Actually, you should replace ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) with ForEach(tasks). It might be because the change in identity caused by the change in isCompleted. The identity should be stable.

@dev_dev Also, I would not recommend declaring an id property on a @Model - that will conflict with the id that every PersistentModel has, and might cause problems later on. I would rename it to uuid or something like that.

You could always add a command menu item and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. But, the only way to do something like this without a command menu is to monitor the input events:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query private var tasks: [TaskModel]
    @State private var selections: Set<TaskModel> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selections) {
            ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
                HStack {
                    
                    Button("complete") {
                        markTaskCompleted(task: task)
                    }
                    
                    Text("\(task.name) - \(task.isCompleted ? "Completed" : "Not Completed")")
                }
                // How to perform keyboard shortcut on the selected row?
            }
        }
        
        .onKeyPress(action: { keyPress in
            if keyPress.characters == "c" && keyPress.modifiers == .command {
                markTaskCompleted(task: nil)
            }
            return .handled
        })
        
        
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func markTaskCompleted(task: TaskModel?) {
        if task != nil {
            withAnimation {
                task!.isCompleted.toggle()
            }
        } else {
            withAnimation {
                for selection in selections {
                    selection.isCompleted.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = TaskModel(id: UUID(), name: "Task \(tasks.count + 1)", isCompleted: false)
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
}

@Model
class TaskModel {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String, isCompleted: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
}

Here,
        .onKeyPress(action: { keyPress in
            if keyPress.characters == "c" && keyPress.modifiers == .command {
                markTaskCompleted(task: nil)
            }
            return .handled
        })

...

    private func markTaskCompleted(task: TaskModel?) {
        if task != nil {
            withAnimation {
                task!.isCompleted.toggle()
            }
        } else {
            withAnimation {
                for selection in selections {
                    selection.isCompleted.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }

We check if the key combination CMD + C is pressed and call markTaskCompleted which toggles all the selections.
